# How to show indent dots in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]
[image]

As you can see here there are no indent dots on my vscode although I have turned on render white space

Could it be one of my extensions messing with it?

Can someone help me turn on the dots that shows indentation like in the 3rd image?

Answer (score 8):

You must add `"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"` parameter in your vscode `settings.json` file.